# SyntaxError: unknown: interface is a reserved word in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

If in a React component file I define an interface for the state:

```
interface IState {
}
```

And try to compile it with `babel.transform` I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: unknown: interface is a reserved word in strict mode
```

Is this expected behaviour? How can I get this to compile?

I am using:

```
"babel-cli": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
"babel-preset-typescript": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
```

on `Mac OSX 10.11.6`.

Comment: could you please give some more info on how you are compiling it.

Comment: can you show your **.babelrc** and **tslint.json** files ?

Comment: You should never prefix variables/types/interfaces with `I`. It is bad practice. Just call it `State` without the `I`. This way you could change it to a `type` later (if needed) without refactoring a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is expected behavior. The interface keyword is reserved in strict mode, and trying to use it in a JavaScript file will result in a syntax error.

To compile TypeScript code, including interfaces, with Babel, you need to use the appropriate Babel preset for TypeScript, which is @babel/preset-typescript in the latest versions of Babel.

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

Comment: In my case, the solution was to add `'@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-react'` as presets. The `@babel/preset-env` is already present in my babel/craco configuration. This was also a problem I only faced when using Storybook v7. 

Adding this, in case it can help somebody struggling with this